# Is there a way to combine features there is correlated but is important(time series) in a classification problem?

Tags: classification, correlation, multicollinearity

Suppose I have variables indicating **access by months**, **consults by months** (and other variables) and I want to predict the *digital propension*.

| Digital_acess_mont01 | Digital_acess_mont02 | Digital_acess_mont03 | transfer_mont01 | transfer_mont03 | transfer_mont03 | *digital propension* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 23 | 24 | 3 | 8 | 4 | 1 |
| 23 | 25 | 23 | 5 | 6 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . | . |

Is there a way to combine this information, aggregating acess by month , and do this to tranfers too ? keep in mind the last months are **more important** than others.

here the biggest problem is multicollinearity in the dataset.

thanks.

Comment: Why is multicollinearity a problem for you?

Comment: don't you think it's a problem? I think several correlated variables can increase the error